# laravel 5.1 admin role in middleware using Entrust

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, middleware, entrust

I am trying to filter route using 'auth' and 'auth.admin' middleware which should be like laravel 4.2's Route::filter. But it's not working.
Here is my route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'auth.admin']], function()
{
   // ... 
});
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'auth.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAdmin::class,
    'role' => Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
    'permission' => Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
    'ability' => Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
];
```

RedirectIfAdmin.php

```
        <?php

        namespace App\Http\Middleware;

        use Closure;
        use Entrust;
        class RedirectIfAdmin
        {
            /**
             * Handle an incoming request.
             *
             * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
             * @param  \Closure  $next
             * @return mixed
             */
            public function handle($request, Closure $next)
            {
                if (!Entrust::hasRole(config('customConfig.roles.admin'))) {
                    return redirect()->route('dashboard')
                                ->with('error', 'Access Denied');
                }
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the problem you're facing, any error ?

Comment: redirect loop problem

Comment: can u show me where is your route('dashboard') pointing.?

Comment: Route::get('dashboard', array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@dashboard'));
And 
return view('dashboard')
                    ->with('title','Dashboard')

Comment: And I used this after successfull attempt
 return redirect()->intended('dashboard');

Answer (score 0):

As u said that ur `dashboard` route is for authenticated user,
But ur checking if user is not in `admin role` send to dashboard, and when he is sent to dashboard he is redirected back, probably due to another middleware kick in, and that send back to login and from login again to dashboard, so just remove `!` from ur if condition.

Comment: thank you, @rummykhan . I also send  normal users to dashboard limiting some facility . however, I find a solution Entrust 's role:admin feature as it does not need an extra middleware. 
Thank You again